# Xampp на Ubuntu 10/04

Tags: ubuntu

Установил XAMPP на ubuntu 10.04 и все работает и база и пхп, а вот установить сязь при инсталяции CMS не могу. Подскажите как быть. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Ну проверяешь на каком хосте у тебя база крутится, скорее всего это localhostпотом порт на котором крутится БД.

Answer (score 1):

Проверить, как сказано выше, хост и порт.Проверить логин и пароль пользователя БД.Проверить в БД есть ли такой пользователь и какие у него права.